# how to install cmake version 3.12 using Homebrew

Tags: cmake, homebrew

I need to use the old version for cmake but I can't find the formula in homebrew, is that a way to install cmake 3.12 using Homebrew?

EDITED: the solution presented here is much more objective considering the answers from the previous question.

Comment: Duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Brief

```sh
# install cmake  3.12.4
brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/raw/a3b64391ebace30b84de8e7997665a1621c0b2c0/Formula/cmake.rb
```

#### Detail

You could install it from specific formula file.

1. Go to [homebrew/homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core), the place where package formula is stored.
2. Use the search bar to [search "cmake" in this repository](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/search?o=desc&q=cmake&s=committer-date&type=Commits).
3. Find the specific commit you want.
4. Enter it. And find the **RAW** url for this `cmake.rb` file.
5. Install it with `brew install url-to-cmake.rb`.

Comment: Just found the problem is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula

Comment: This does not work anymore

Comment: Error: Installation of cmake from a GitHub commit URL is unsupported! `brew extract cmake` to a stable tap on GitHub instead.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the answer. Homebrew dropped the support for installation from url. @Yingchen

Comment: If you download the older formula file (e.g. with `wget`), you can install it from source: `brew install -s ./url-to-cmake.rb`